# Why is $proj_{Ox} \overrightarrow{M_1M_2} = |{\overrightarrow{M_1M_2}}| \cos \varphi$ true?

Tags: analytic-geometry, projection

The following image comes from the text and is a good visual aid for the descriptions to follow.

[image]

---

**Background**

The book defines the *projection* of a directed segment in this way:

> The projection $proj_{Ox} \overrightarrow{M_1M_2}$ of the directed segment $\overrightarrow{M_1M_2}$ onto the x-axis is the magnitude of the directed segment $\overrightarrow{M_{1x}M_{2x}}$, whose initial point $M_{1x}$ is the projection of the beginning of the segment $\overrightarrow{M_1M_2}$ and the terminating point $M_{2x}$ is the projection of the end of the segment $\overrightarrow{M_1M_2}$.

After which they establish the relation

$$
proj_{Ox} \overrightarrow{M_1M_2} = x_2 - x_1 \tag{1}
$$

where $x_i$ is the coordinate of point $M_i$, for $i = 1,2$. I understand relation $(1)$.

Then they go on to establish a different formulation for $proj_{Ox} \overrightarrow{M_1M_2}$ which goes as follows:

> We displace the directed segment $\overrightarrow{M_1M_2}$ parallel to itself so that its beginning coincides with some point of the x-axis (in the above figure, this point is $M_{1x}$). We designate as $\varphi$ the least angle between the direction of the x-axis and that of the segment $\overrightarrow{M_{1x}M_{2}^*}$ resulting from the indicated parallel displacement of the segment $\overrightarrow{M_1M_2}$. Note that the angle $\varphi$ is contained between $0$ and $\pi$. Then it is evident that the angle $\pi$ is acute if the direction of the segment $\overrightarrow{M_{1x}M_{2x}}$ coincides with that of $Ox$ and is obtuse if the direction of the segment $\overrightarrow{M_{1x}M_{2x}}$ is opposite to that of $Ox$.

Then they go on to say that from this, it is easy to ascertain the validity of the following new relation

$$
proj_{Ox} \overrightarrow{M_1M_2} = |{\overrightarrow{M_1M_2}}| \cos \varphi \tag{2}
$$

where $|\overrightarrow{M_1M_2}|$ denotes the length of the segment $\overrightarrow{M_1M_2}$.

---

**Question**

I have no idea how they came up with $(2)$ without any more additional information. For instance, if we take $ M_{1x}M_{2x}M_2^* $ to be a right-triangle with the hypotenuse designated by the segment $\overrightarrow{M_{1x}M_{2}^*}$, then we can show that $(2)$ is true. But we are not given this information. **How do we derive (2) rigorously?**

Comment: Note that (presumably, based on the picture) $\overrightarrow{M_{1x}M_2^*} = \overrightarrow{M_1M_2}$. Raise a perpendicular from $M_2^*$ up to $Ox$ and form right-angled triangle. The base of that triangle is $\operatorname{proj}_{Ox}\overrightarrow{M_{1x}M_2^*} = \operatorname{proj}_{Ox}\overrightarrow{M_1M_2}$. Now use high school trig.

Comment: @TheoBendit why is the base of that triangle $proj_{Ox} \overrightarrow{M_1M_2}$?

Comment: It's the base of $\operatorname{proj}_{Ox}\overrightarrow{M_{1x}M_2^*}$ because that's basically how the perpendicular projection onto a line/vector is defined. This vector is the same as $\operatorname{proj}_{Ox}\overrightarrow{M_1M_2}$ because $\overrightarrow{M_{1x}M_2^*}$ is the same as $\overrightarrow{M_1M_2}$.

Comment: @TheoBendit got it, thank you. My Euclidean geometry knowledge isn't strong; hopefully that won't hinder my study of analytic geometry.